# Is it possible to modify order of events? (Open_Form of subform)

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, subform

Working on MS Access 2010.

As far as I know, when there is a subform, subform should open before parent.

As can be seen in [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3) aswell (it refers to 2010, 2007 inter alia):

> ...the events for the subform and its controls (such as Open, Current, Enter, and GotFocus) occur before the events for the form...

Is there a way to make Form_Open event of parent fire before that of child?

The thing is that in my case, the order of the events did change to this:

```
Parent: Form_Open-START

Child: Form_Open-START (when setting RecordSource in Form_Open of parent)

Child: Form_Open-End

Parent: Form_Open-END
```

While it should be:

```
Child: Form_Open-START

Child: Form_Open-End

Parent: Form_Open-START

Parent: Form_Open-END
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, I'm treating this bug as a sort of corruption or damage of accdb file (maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2#bm1) has something to do with it). I've seen it several times in MS Access, the need of refreshing objects in certain ways for them to "click" back to place.

Surely enough, when I remove or add an event to that form, things "click" back to behave as they are supposed to,
In my case: child events before parent events.

Of course, straight afterwards, I return what I removed or remove what I've added. They weren't the cause, only a refresh was needed.

I hope this helps someone else as well.